# Formula for $\sum_{d|n} \frac {\mu(d)}d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function, dirichlet-convolution

I feel like I've seen a formula somewhere for $\displaystyle \sum_{d|n} \frac {\mu(d)}d$, but I can't remember what it is and can't find it. Does anybody know of a formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d} = \prod_{p|n}(1-p^{-1}) = \frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's function.